# Cannot access class CoroutineScope. Check module classpath

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a kotlin multiplatform project and have implemented a simple repository class in the common module to make an API call. I pass in the coroutine scope as an argument to be able to use the `viewModelScope` and defaults it to a scope defined in the common code (because of iOS).

When calling the function from the android project Android Studio complains and says `Cannot access class 'kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies`, however, the project compiles just fine and runs as expected. So it seems like this is an IDE hickup.

I found this issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-24575
Is it related? And how can I get rid of it?

Comment: Did you manage to solve your issue? I exeprience the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

the issue you referred to, is duplicated with this https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-20511 and state of this issue is `fixed`.

Comment: Yeah, I dont think any of them are directly related to my issue. I might open a new issue.